# Django Template : Escape <script> tag only when showing RichText

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am currently developing a blog site with Django from  scratch where people can write the description in a RichText Field where they can use HTML features like Bold, Italic. Heading, Add Image, Add URL etc.
When rendering it from template I want to show all the tags as HTML. The only thing I want to escape is the script tag i.e. render <p>something</p> as  <p>something</p>but <script> alert("Hello world"); </script> as &lt;script&gt; alert("Hello world"); &lt;/script&gt;

How can I do that?

Comment: You don't want to show tags?

Comment: I want to show all the tags as HTML elements except for the script tag. I've got my answer already, thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can opt for `django-html_sanitizer` app. You can use it to remove/escape all tags, except those that you choose to leave.

Example usage in a template:

```
{% strip_html your_text "em, b, code, li" %}
```